# Load the text in a textbox on startup C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, save

I've been struggleing with this issue for a while now and I have no idea how this should work.

I have a WinForm Application with a textbox in it and when i write something in it and close the winform it doesnt save it (Obviously)

How would I make it save the text I put in the textbox and then when I open the WinForm Application it has the information (text) in the textbox saved.

Comment: Do you have any statements inside `_TextChanged()`? Show some related codes if possible

Comment: I dont have any code, I deleted the project with the code in it because I couldnt make anything work, I would of provided you with code but I dont know how to create the fucntion that actually saved the text in the textbox.

Comment: If you have deleted your code then you have no question to ask.  Ask again later when you do have code.

Comment: @JK. Thats not it. It was not the code I was having issues with. I thought i made that clear in the question, I dont know how to create the function to save the textbox data, so when I start the application again it reads that data and its still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Form_OnClosing event and save the textbox data to your app.config.  Then, when you run the application, read from the app.config and display the information in the textbox.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {          
     txtSaveOnClose.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText;
 }

 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText = txtSaveOnClose.Text;
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
 }
```

Comment: That seems like it could work , I need to go look up how to save the textbox fata into the app.config, il get back with an update